# Click listener when tab is clicked - angular2 and ng bootstrap

Tags: angular, tabs, ng-bootstrap

I have the following html code snippet. I am using angular2, ng-bootstrap ng tab. My question is how do i invoke a method click when a tab is clicked? 
I added (click) but I see that the method fetchNews() is not getting invoked at all when I click on the tab. What am I doing wrong?

```
  <ngb-tab title="Active" (click)="fetchNews('active')">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <table class="table table-sm table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Attachment</th>
          <th>Start Date</th>
          <th>End Date</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of news">
          <td>{{item.title}}</td>
          <td>{{item.description | ellipsis:25}}</td>
          <td>{{item.attachmentUrl | ellipsis:25}}</td>
          <td>{{item.startDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a'}}</td>
          <td>{{item.endDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a'}}</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" (click)="showNewsModal('active',item, true)">
              Modify
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can declare `ngbTabTitle` template and catch click event there:

```
<ngb-tab>
  <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
      <div (click)="fetchNews('active')">Active</div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbTabContent>
    <table class="table table-sm table-striped" (click)="fetchNews('active')">
      ...
    </table>
  </ng-template>
<ngb-tab>
```

Comment: I noticed one thing though. This works only if I click on the tab title. If i click anywhere else inside the tab other than the title then it doesn't recognize the click. How can i make a listener to listen to click anywhere on that tab not just the tab title.

Comment: I apologize that I was not able to explain my question clearly. What I meant is that, is it possible to move the click listener at <ngb-tab> level. Because the ng-template div is not covering up the entire tab. the ng-template div click listener only works if the mouse pointer is right on the tab title "Active". If the mouse is slightly away from the title but still inside the tab, the click listener doesn't work. I tried <ng-tab select="fetchNews('active')" >but that didnt work. I have also tried <ng-tab (click)="fetchNews('active')"

Comment: I added click to table. It is inside tab

Comment: I've just notices that `a` tag inside tab has paddings. Check this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/rr1j5EBZQVLkAXRQSbF0?p=preview I added custom class to tab to add some styles.

Comment: I tried this as is and simply doesn't fire the click event

Answer (score 27):

The below should work correctly every time.

```js
fetchNews(evt: any) {
  console.log(evt); // has nextId that you can check to invoke the desired function
}
```

```html
<ngb-tabset (tabChange)="fetchNews($event)">
  <ngb-tab title="Active">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <table class="table table-sm table-striped">
        ...
      </table>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

Comment: Just a simple improvement is to add an id on ngb-tab like ngb-tab id="tab-selectbyid1"

Comment: Yea, also recommend adding the [id] input on the ngb-tabset. Also, ngbTabSet has been deprecated as of ngBootstrap 6.0.0

Answer (score 5):

1. In Html, You have to add `tabChange` Event, in `ngb-tabset` tag
2. Set unique id in event `ngb-tab`
3. In .ts file, perform action of change tab

**.html file**

```
<ngb-tabset (tabChange)="changeTab($event)">   <- Add Event 
    <ngb-tab [id]="0">                         <- SET ID
        <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab [id]="1">                          <- SET ID
        <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

**.ts file**

```
changeTab(event) {
    if (event.nextId == '0') {
        // Action for first tab
    }

    else if (event.nextId == '1') {
        // Action for second tab
    }
}
```

Comment: this can't be applied as it works only and only if you change the tab, the question is how to capture click event even if you are not changing the tab

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but for the click event to work it has to be set on the ngb-tabset (which I don't see in your code and usually bootstrap tabs have that tag) and not on the ngb-tab
`<ngb-tabset type="pills" id="myId" class="myClass" (click)="togglePanel($event)">`

Answer (score 0):

***Simple solution:***  :

Use ***ngbTabTitle*** like below .. and you can ***trigger an event*** from here
like below code

```
 <ngb-tabset>
      <ngb-tab  >
          <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
              <div (click)="getTransactionList()">Transactions</div>
          </ng-template>

        <ng-template ngbTabContent >
          <table class="custom-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>TransactionID</th>
                <th>Sender</th>
                <th>Recipient</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let Transaction of getTransactions | slice:0:10; let i=index">
                <td>{{Transaction.id}}</td>
                <td>{{Transaction.senderId}}</td>
                <td>{{Transaction.recipientId}}</td>
                <td>{{Transaction.timestamp}}</td>
                <td>{{Transaction.amount}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>


      <ngb-tab>
               // your code 
     </ngb-tab>

     <ngb-tab>
               // your code 
     </ngb-tab>

<ngb-tabset>
```

Answer (score 0):

its a simple **css trick** you can apply like this.
Modifying user1752112's answer a little bit.

```
<ngb-tab>
  <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
      <div style="padding: 8px 10px;" (click)="fetchNews('active')">Active</div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbTabContent>
    <table class="table table-sm table-striped" (click)="fetchNews('active')">
    </table>
  </ng-template>
<ngb-tab>
```

in your css file use this.

```
::ng-deep .nav-tabs .nav-link {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using Angular 6,8. Please use `(select)="tabSelected()".`

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 11, use (selectTab)

```html
<tabset>
  <tab (selectTab)="doSomething()">
    <ng-template tabHeading>
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'copy']"></fa-icon>
    </ng-template>
    <foo1-tab></foo1-tab>
  </tab>
  <tab>
    <ng-template tabHeading>
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'cogs']"></fa-icon>
    </ng-template>
    <foo2-tab></foo2-tab>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```